# assembly > my atoi function not working with int 21h ah 3Fh

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, atoi

I made an `atoi` function in assembly and when I test it with already defined string it works fine, but when I use `int 21h / 3Fh` to get string from user (which I then store and pass to this function) it gives me some senseless value.

I'm doing this for school and I put it in some library that I'm making, except this it contains `itoa` function with which I'm not having problems.

The functions converts string, whose address is previously stored in `SI`, into an integer stored in `AX`.
I use `itoa` to display content of `AX`.

Hope someone knows what is the problem.

This is the not working example:

```
mov ah, 3fh  ;get string
mov dx, stri
int 21h

mov si, stri  ;convert it
call z_atoi

stri db '$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$'
```

The working example:

```
mov si, stri
call z_atoi

stri db '789$'
```

The function:

```
z_atoi: ;z_atoi(si=str) return ax=[number]
    xor dh, dh  ;needs to be zero for dx==dl
    xor ax, ax  ;the number
    xor cx, cx  ;the character
  z_atoi1:
    test cx, cx    ;is this the first character
    je z_atoi2   ;if so skip this
      imul ax, 10  ;multiply by 10
  z_atoi2:
    mov bx, si
    add bx, cx
    mov dl, [bx]  ;get next character
    sub dl, 30h   ;ascii to integer
    add ax, dx    ;add to the number
    inc cx    ;next character
    inc bx
    cmp byte[bx], '$'  ;check if there are any more characters
    je z_atoi3
    cmp byte[bx], 0
    je z_atoi3
    cmp byte[bx], 0ah ;<--THIS WAS WHAT I WAS MISSING, THANKS
    je z_atoi3
    jmp z_atoi1
  z_atoi3:
    ret
```

Comment: I think `int 21h/3Fh` ends in a CR when reading from console. Try checking for that along with the '$' and 0.

Comment: Step through the code line by line. It's a short function so it shouldn't take long.

Comment: thanks @Frank Kotler, I was sure I have checked that already, but looks like something changed